# Extract Values from CSV File Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file where the data is organized into two columns.

[image]

How can I get the negative sentiments and positives saved in a separate csv file. My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/epinions3.csv')

df_neg = df.loc[['Neg']] # get all negative sentiments and then save to a file 

df_pos = # get all positive sentiments and save to a file 

print(df_neg)
```

Comment: `df[df['class'] == 'Neg']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['class'] == 'Neg'].to_csv('negative.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to save each row as a separate file.

Comment: `for row in range(df.shape[0]):
        df.iloc[row].to_csv(f'filename{row}.csv', index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below two lines in order to filter and save files:

```
df[df['class']==Neg].to_csv('Neg.csv')

df[df['class']==Pos].to_csv('Pos.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/epinions3.csv')

df_neg = df.loc[df['class'] == 'Neg'] # get all negative sentiments

df_pos = df.loc[df['class'] == 'Pos'] # get all positive sentiments

df_neg.to_csv("neg.csv")    # write neg to csv
df_pos.to_csv("pos.csv")    # write pos to csv
```